# Sending notification to a specific user based on realtime database data (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase realtime database like this:
[image]

I want to send a user notification if userState changes from `0` to `1`.
the thing is userState is changed by another phone or device and the app might not be open on the phone we are trying to change its userState, so I cant use `EventListener`.
how can I do this? is there any tutorial I can follow?

Comment: When does he change the status?

Comment: @MohammadKhairPK for example there are two users. user 1 does something on their device that changes userState of user 1 and then user 1 gets a notification.

Comment: okay then, you have the user 1 info, right? if yes you can send the notification using (for ex) php api from the user 1 token

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: @MohammadKhairPK I'm kind of new to android and firebase. can you link a tutorial on how to use PHP api? appreciate it.

Comment: @Anthraxff check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a notification using PHP files **(with server side)** [check this link](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/send+push+notification+php)

Or you can send them from android to android **(without server side)** [check this link](https://blog.usejournal.com/send-device-to-device-push-notifications-without-server-side-code-238611c143)